# Corsair K95 keyboard qemu passthrough to Windows 10. Not working

Tags: kvm, hardware, qemu, libvirt

I cannot get my keyboard to pass through to the virtual machine. It disconnects from my host machine like it is going to work, but does not. Interestingly, in order to reuse my keyboard on my host machine after, I have to physically disconnect and reconnect the keyboard.

Originally, I thought this was a problem with USB 3.0, however, I am able to mount my USB 3.0 thumb drive through a USB 3.0 port. Moreover, my wireless combo keyboard and mouse: Logitech k260, works. That combo keyboard + mouse is USB 2.0, through an USB 2.0 hub, into a USB 3.0 port. My RAT7 mouse also works through a USB 2.0 port.

Everything else passes through perfectly. My GPU is working, I am getting 60 FPS in games, I got sound to work (albeit in a round-about way), etc. Only this keyboard.

## Update:

So after some plugging things in and out, trying to live attach the keyboard post boot, etc. It appears that the keyboard is going through to the Virtual Machine. However, the keyboard is still not working. The keyboard is showing up as a `USB Composite Device` in Windows Device Manager. Even after installing drivers, attempting to remove and reinstall drivers it is still not working. <strike>I am going to attempt to boot into safe mode and see if it cannot be fixed from there</strike>. However, I feel as though this may not work. Attempting to reboot into safe mode and fix keyboard did not work.

**keyboard**: [Corsair K95 RGB](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16823816023)

**Host Software**

- **kernel**: 4.15.15-1-vfio (Patched with ACS via `yaourt linux-vfio` from kernel 4.15.14-1)
- **Manjaro**: Arch based system.

**Host Hardware**

- **CPU**: AMD Ryzen 1700x 8 cores, 16 threads
- **Motherboard**: Asrock x370 gaming x
- **Host GPU**: Radeon HD 7970
- **Guest GPU**: Radeon HD 6950
- **RAM**: 16GB DDR4

**related packages** (pacman -Q | grep [qemu, virt, vfio])

```
qemu 2.11.1-2
qemu-arch-extra 2.11.1-2
libvirt 4.0.0-1
libvirt-glib 1.0.0-1
libvirt-python2 4.0.0-1
virt-install 1.5.1-1
virt-manager 1.5.1-1
linux-vfio 4.15.15-1
linux-vfio-docs 4.15.15-1
linux-vfio-headers 4.15.15-1
```

**Virtual Machine setup** following this guide: [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Bypassing_the_IOMMU_groups_.28ACS_override_patch.29)

**VM Setup (virt-manager)**

- **Overview**:

  - KVM hypervisor
  - x86_64 architecture
  - /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 emulator
  - UEFIx86_64:/usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd firmware
  - Q35 chipset
- **CPUs**: 8 allocated, manually set topology: 4 sockets, 4 cores, 2 threads
- **Memory**: 8192 MiB

**VM xml file** (sudo virsh edit win10)

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>win10</name>
  <uuid>ef3ed034-abec-4f02-9771-a780012b73ea</uuid>
  <memory unit='KiB'>8388608</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>8388608</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static' current='8'>32</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-2.11'>hvm</type>
    <loader readonly='yes' type='pflash'>/usr/share/ovmf/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd</loader>
    <nvram>/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/win10_VARS.fd</nvram>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv>
      <relaxed state='on'/>
      <vapic state='on'/>
      <spinlocks state='on' retries='8191'/>
    </hyperv>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-model' check='partial'>
    <model fallback='allow'/>
    <topology sockets='4' cores='4' threads='2'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='localtime'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
    <timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/home/drew/Virtual Machines/win10.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='sata'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/drew/Downloads/Win10_1709_English_x64.iso'/>
      <target dev='sdb' bus='sata'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='sata' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1f' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pcie-root'/>
    <controller type='pci' index='1' model='dmi-to-pci-bridge'>
      <model name='i82801b11-bridge'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1e' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='2' model='pci-bridge'>
      <model name='pci-bridge'/>
     <target chassisNr='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='3' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='3' port='0x10'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='4' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='4' port='0x11'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='5' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='5' port='0x12'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='6' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='6' port='0x8'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-ehci1'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1d' function='0x7'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci1'>
      <master startport='0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1d' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci2'>
      <master startport='2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1d' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='ich9-uhci3'>
      <master startport='4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1d' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:6f:f8:5a'/>
      <source network='default'/>
      <model type='rtl8139'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='spicevmc'>
      <target type='virtio' name='com.redhat.spice.0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x0d' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x0d' slot='0x00' function='0x1'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x06' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <vendor id='0x046d'/>
        <product id='0xc52e'/>
      </source>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='usb' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <vendor id='0x0781'/>
        <product id='0x5581'/>
      </source>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='3'/>
    </hostdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

**lsusb**

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 1b1c:1b11 Corsair K95 RGB Mechanical Gaming Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0738:1708 Mad Catz, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:0719 Microsoft Corp. Xbox 360 Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1908:0226 GEMBIRD 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 046d:c52e Logitech, Inc. MK260 Wireless Combo Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**IOMMU groups**

```
IOMMU Group 0 00:01.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
IOMMU Group 10 00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B [1022:1454]
IOMMU Group 11 00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 59)
IOMMU Group 11 00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
IOMMU Group 12 00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0 [1022:1460]
IOMMU Group 12 00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1 [1022:1461]
IOMMU Group 12 00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2 [1022:1462]
IOMMU Group 12 00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3 [1022:1463]
IOMMU Group 12 00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4 [1022:1464]
IOMMU Group 12 00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5 [1022:1465]
IOMMU Group 12 00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric Device 18h Function 6 [1022:1466]
IOMMU Group 12 00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7 [1022:1467]
IOMMU Group 13 03:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43b9] (rev 02)
IOMMU Group 13 03:00.1 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43b5] (rev 02)
IOMMU Group 13 03:00.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:43b0] (rev 02)
IOMMU Group 13 04:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
IOMMU Group 13 04:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
IOMMU Group 13 04:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
IOMMU Group 13 04:03.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
IOMMU Group 13 04:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
IOMMU Group 13 04:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
IOMMU Group 13 04:07.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
IOMMU Group 13 06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
IOMMU Group 14 0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti XT [Radeon HD 7970/8970 OEM / R9 280X] [1002:6798]
IOMMU Group 14 0c:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7870 XT / 7950/7970] [1002:aaa0]
IOMMU Group 15 0d:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cayman PRO [Radeon HD 6950] [1002:6719]
IOMMU Group 15 0d:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cayman/Antilles HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6930/6950/6970/6990] [1002:aa80]
IOMMU Group 16 11:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:145a]
IOMMU Group 16 11:00.2 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor [1022:1456]
IOMMU Group 16 11:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] USB3 Host Controller [1022:145c]
IOMMU Group 17 12:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device [1022:1455]
IOMMU Group 17 12:00.2 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7901] (rev 51)
IOMMU Group 17 12:00.3 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:1457]
IOMMU Group 1 00:01.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1453]
IOMMU Group 2 00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
IOMMU Group 3 00:03.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
IOMMU Group 4 00:03.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1453]
IOMMU Group 5 00:03.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1453]
IOMMU Group 6 00:04.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
IOMMU Group 7 00:07.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
IOMMU Group 8 00:07.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B [1022:1454]
IOMMU Group 9 00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
```

**/var/log/libvirt/qemu/win10.log**: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/u8E2L0Xg)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured out a solution, albeit, it is a more of a work around than a proper solution. So I still cannot, as far as I am aware, able to pass through my keyboard directly.

What I did to solve this was instead to first remove my wireless keyboard/mouse passthrough and add my good mouse as passthrough instead. So my wireless combo is for my Linux host and the good keyboard is on the Linux host as well, only the good mouse is for Windows only.

I then setup a display spice server to have Windows operate as a window in Linux, however, there is no display only a black screen here (which is fine). Now, I click into this window with my wireless combo and control windows with my good mouse and my good keyboard's keystrokes are being passed through as well!

I was a bit worried that this would cause a bit of latency, however, after a test round in Dirty Bomb I felt no noticeable latency in either mouse or keyboard. So it seems to work perfectly fine. I would still prefer to pass through the hardware directly, but I cannot complain.